# Find the Fourier series for the function:

Tags: functions, fourier-series

Function $f(x)=\frac{  \pi -x }{ 2 }$$,x $$\ \in \left( - \pi,  \pi  \right)$

As I understand the formula looks like this:  $$\boldsymbol{ƒ}(x) \sim \frac{ a_{0}  }{ 2 }+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }\left( a_{n} \cos{nx}+b_{n}\sin{nx}    \right)$$

All three necessary coefficients look like this:

1)$$a_{0} =  \frac{ 1 }{  \pi  } \int\limits_{- \pi }^{ \pi }ƒ(x)$$ 
2)$$a_{n} =  \frac{ 1 }{  \pi  } \int\limits_{- \pi }^{ \pi }ƒ(x)\cos{nx} dx$$ 
3)$$b_{n} =  \frac{ 1 }{  \pi  } \int\limits_{- \pi }^{ \pi }ƒ(x)\sin{nx} dx$$

I solved:

$a_{0} =  \pi$,
$a_{n} =  \frac{ \sin{ \pi n}  }{ n }$,
$b_{n} =  \frac{  \pi n \cos{ \pi n} - \sin{ \pi n}  }{  \pi n^{2}  }$

Were $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ found correctly? If not how to solve this correctly, If it's not hard can you please provide whole step-by-step solution.

Comment: $a_{0}$ is wrong, it should just be $\pi$. $a_{n} = 0$ as $\sin(n \pi) = 0$. $\cos(n \pi) = (-1)^{n}$ and so $b_{n} = $?

Comment: sorry, right I mistyped $a_{0} = \pi$

Comment: $b_{n}= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$?